# Java - JCheckBox Filters Against a List

Tags: java, swing, search, jcheckbox

I have a `List`, that included JPA `Entity` objects of a certain type. Their `reference` String values are displayed in a `JList` for the user to see.

I want my user to be able to select filters as JCheckBoxes in the UI such as 'only from Client **x**', or 'only of Type **x**' and dynamically filter the Entity List.

I had thought to just keep a copy of `static List completeList;` and `static List filteredList;` and then just run individual filter methods each time a new filter is selected in the UI to update `filteredList`, which would work fine until you have to un-select a single filter and leave the others selected (at which point it all falls apart).

Every situation I think through fall apart at one point or another, usually when trying to select multiple filters of from one Menu.

An example of my thought pattern that checks all the filters to determine what needs to go in the new JList;

```
public static void filterList(){
    List filteredList = new ArrayList<Job>(StoredDataClass.completeList);

    if(clientSmithsCheckBox.isSelected()){
        for(Job job : filteredList){
            if(!job.getClient.equals(clientSmithsCheckBox.getText())){
                filteredList.remove(job);
            }
        }
    }

    ....... // Check other filters here etc.

    if(clientBobAndCoCheckBox.isSelected()){
        for(Job job : filteredList){
            if(!job.getClient.equals(clientBobAndCoCheckBox.getText())){
                filteredList.remove(job);
            }
        }
    }
```

Even if clientBobAndCoCheckBox is selected, no jobs with that client will show in the final list, because we already removed them all because another client was already selected. Now, we could *add* to the list instead but we would face similar problems of having add stuff that shouldn't be there etc.

This is obviously possible, because this type of filtering system is common practice (example, excel). Although this is more of a design question, how can I achieve this?

Comment: don't see how/where JMenus come into play nor why filtering by several conditions will fail ;-) Most probably, there's no way around a SSCCE to understand what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'll try and think up some example code then. : S

Comment: The `JMenu`s don't really need to be considered coding wise, it's just that the `JCheckBoxes` will be in `JMenu`s.

Comment: that's not a SSCCE ;-) Anyway, it's a logic problem: you need some criteria which takes into account the state of _all_ checkboxes (or better: some data object that's mapped to the checkboxes' state)

Comment: _JMenus don't really need to be considered coding wise_ well, then that's just clutter, nothing you need to mention at all :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I actually can create a properly compilable SSCCE for this problem. It would be huge.

Comment: _SSCCE  ... It would be huge_ that's a contradiction in itself ;-) Be sure you understand what/why/how it is/to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short (and raw!) example of how you could organize your logic. It's in the context of SwingX (which supports sorting/filtering of a JList just the same way as a JTable) because I'm lazy - but you can apply it to your own environment easily.

Think of your criteria as a collection of filters which can be on or off, and then combine them with OR (if one or more is selected) or turn off if none is selected. The sole "trick" is to evaluate *all* of the checkboxes' states wheneven one of them is changed:

```
final JXList list = new JXList(new DefaultComboBoxModel(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
list.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
final List<RowFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
filters.add(new MyRowFilter("de"));
filters.add(new MyRowFilter("ar"));
final List<JCheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<>();
ActionListener l = new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> orCandidates = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < boxes.size(); i++) {
            if (boxes.get(i).isSelected())
                orCandidates.add(filters.get(i));
        }
        RowFilter<Object, Object> or = orCandidates.isEmpty() ? null :
            RowFilter.orFilter(orCandidates);
        list.setRowFilter(or);
    }

};
JCheckBox first = new JCheckBox("de");
first.addActionListener(l);
boxes.add(first);
JCheckBox second = new JCheckBox("ar");
second.addActionListener(l);
boxes.add(second);

JComponent content = new JPanel();
content.add(new JScrollPane(list));
for (JCheckBox box : boxes) {
    content.add(box);
}
showInFrame(content, "filters");

// just for completeness, the custom RowFilter
public static class MyRowFilter extends RowFilter {

    private String text;
    public MyRowFilter(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean include(Entry entry) {
        Locale locale = (Locale) entry.getValue(0);
        return locale.getLanguage().contains(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I apologies if I don't get around to testing it and accepting it for a little while. I'll have to get my head around it first when I get the chance. Thanks again.